# Grafana integration with springboot and postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, grafana

I am trying to use *Grafana* for visualization. I have a *Spring-boot* application which is integrated with *PostgreSQL*. I want to fetch the data from Postgres and show it in *Grafana*.

So far, I have found maven dependency for grafana which is as below :

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.appnexus.grafana-client/grafana-api-java-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.appnexus.grafana-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>grafana-api-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

*Can anyone please help with the tutorials examples?*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just visualized the PostgreSQL database metrics on grafana then you can use this [plugin](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/postgres/).

However if you want to view the Spring Boot related metrics ( http response status, performance, jvm stats, connection pool stats etc.) then a more popular way is to setup Prometheus as the time series datastore and metrics scraper from where graphana can generate the visualization. For detailed information on setup of each component you can refer to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-monitoring-via-prometheus-grafana) or [this](https://stackabuse.com/monitoring-spring-boot-apps-with-micrometer-prometheus-and-grafana) article.
There are even ready made grafana dashboards for Spring Boot like [this](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/6756). Of course this too uses Prometheus.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply.. I want through all the tutorials is there a way that I can call grafana from my spring boot code and the graph should show up.

Comment: Graphana pulls information and it is not pushed to Graphana. The library you have included in the pom.xml helps you to programatically invoke Graphana ( instead of web ui) to do admin stuff like creating graphana users, datasources, dashboards etc but will not help in actually sending any metric. The correct way to let graphana show your spring boot stats is already explained in shared articles.